# VPN blocking all rival websites

Tags: vpn

Since I downloaded a free VPN, it blocked all rival VPN websites. All other websites work fine but when i try to go on to the Windscribe website it resets the connection.

I have just E-mailed speedify and the said they would never intentionally block any other website so I am assuming it was avast as they also offer a VPN.

[image: Windscribe]
[image: Hotspotsheild]

Even with speedify killed from taskmgr it still resets the connection every time I try to go on the website. How do I undo this ?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @DavidPostill I have just edited it

Comment: Uninstall speedify?

Comment: @DavidPostill I believe it installed some drivers. Will uninstalling it delete the drivers too ?

Comment: @DavidPostill I have just uninstalled it but it still blocks the websites

Comment: Install [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html). re-install Speedify, and uninstall using Revo.

Comment: @harrymc Still not working

Comment: It mat have installed some firewall rules. Try to [Reset the Windows Firewall Rules to Default](https://www.howtogeek.com/201658/how-to-reset-the-windows-firewall-rules-to-default/).

Comment: Did you tried its own uninstall documentation? https://support.speedify.com/article/146-how-do-i-uninstall-speedify

Comment: @OnurSenture I use windows

Comment: Change your DNS to public DNS `8.8.8.8` and see if it'll resolve your issue.

Comment: @BikuBalami Still not working (Worked for a blink second then stopped again)

Comment: Some country(especially if you're in the Middle East), they'll block all the VPN web pages. Try using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hoxx-vpn-proxy/nbcojefnccbanplpoffopkoepjmhgdgh in your browser and see if you can access those websites. It is a small browser extension VPN.

Comment: @F.Ahmed check with hoxx vpn

Comment: @BikuBalami I've just rebooted my PC and the DNS trick worked. Please post as a answer so I can mark it as best. Thanks

Comment: @BikuBalami I've just rebooted my PC and the DNS trick worked. Please post as a answer so I can mark it as best. Thanks

Comment: @BikuBalami Well it worked yesterday. It has stopped again today !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below instructions to resolve the issue.

- First, go to start menu, type `cmd` and press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`, and press `Yes` if it prompts for `UAC dialogue box`.
- Second, type `ipconfig /flushdns` and press `enter`. (Optional: `ipconfig /release` & `ipconfig /renew`)
- Third, change your primary DNS to public DNS `8.8.8.8` & secondary DNS to `8.8.4.4`

Additional steps(may or may not require)

- `Start -> Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network and Sharing Center`
- On the side, there is a `Change Adapter Settings` click on it.
- `Right-Click` on your Adapter `-> Status -> Properties`
- Now if you are using Speedify, you should see `Speedify Routing Driver 6` or something along those lines. Disable it by unticking and then Select it. (Make sure it's selected! The writing should be highlighted with blue!) And then press `Uninstall`.
- Now reconnect and that should fix the problem.

And Finally:

- Instead of installing VPN in your computer use browser extension VPN like [Hoxx](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hoxx-vpn-proxy/nbcojefnccbanplpoffopkoepjmhgdgh) in Chrome. By using this browser VPN you can unlock all the blocked websites and it will work the same as your `Speedify` VPN but only for a browser.

Also, some applications like DynDns updater forcefully change the DNS of your computer. Make sure you're not using such applications if you don't need it absolutely.

P.S. For the second step reference is taken from [here.](https://superuser.com/questions/930780/is-hotspot-shield-safe)

Answer (score 1):

Speedify probably modified your network config in one of a few common places. Try these two.

**Check your hosts file.**

If you see a bunch of entries here to problem websites, you can delete them

On Windows:
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

On Linux:
/etc/hosts

**Check your firewall settings**

Try turning off windows firewall temporarily. If you can access the blocked websites, turn firewall back on and start sifting through all the rules, trying to find something suspicious. Run "wf.msc" to go directly to list of inbound and outbound rules. Turn off rules until you find the ones causing the problem. You can delete them.